# How to get user entered quantity against each option selected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am creating the functionality where the User will select multiple dropdown options and enter a quantity against each option. But I am not sure how to get that quantity against that particular option after they submit the form.

```
<form>
<div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" id="droptxt" class="list" readonly>
        <div id="content" class="content">
         @foreach($states as $state)
                                                
            <div class="list">
                <input type="checkbox" id="market" class="list" value="{{$state['state']}}" />
                <label for="stock" class="list">{{$state['state']}} </label>
                <input type="hidden" class="list quantity" min="1" value="1"/>
            </div>
            @endforeach
                                            
        </div>
    </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
<script>
        var txt = document.getElementById( 'droptxt' ),
            content = document.getElementById( 'content' ),
            list = document.querySelectorAll( '.content input[type="checkbox"]' ),
            quantity = document.querySelectorAll( '.quantity' );

        txt.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
            content.classList.toggle( 'show' )
        } )

        // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
        window.onclick = function( e ) {
            if ( !e.target.matches( '.list' ) ) {
                if ( content.classList.contains( 'show' ) ) content.classList.remove( 'show' )
            }
        }

        list.forEach( function( item, index ) {
            item.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                quantity[ index ].type = ( item.checked ) ? 'number' : 'hidden';
                calc()
            } )
        } )

        quantity.forEach( function( item ) {
            item.addEventListener( 'input', calc )
        } )

        function calc() {
            for ( var i = 0, arr = []; i < list.length; i++ ) {
                if ( list[ i ].checked )
                    arr.push( quantity[ i ].value + ' x ' + list[ i ].value )
            }
            txt.value = arr.join( ', ' )
        }
    </script>
```

You can check this for better understanding https://jsfiddle.net/uh2xya95/1/

Answer (score 0):

just create array input, example add `name="quantity[{{$state['state']}}]"`

```
 @foreach($states as $state)
                                        
    <div class="list">
        <input type="checkbox" id="market" class="list" value="{{$state['state']}}" />
        <label for="stock" class="list">{{$state['state']}} </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity[{{$state['state']}}]" class="list quantity" min="1" value="1"/>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

after you submit the form, the return of `request()->quantity` should be like:

```
[
"Apple" => 1,
"Banana" => 1,
"Pineapple" => 1
]
```

but even the checkbox is not checked, the hidden input always be sent. If you only need the checked checkbox you should use JS to disable unchecked checkbox.